# I want to get folder name of the url but it takes half of it

Tags: php

My code is working in localhost but when I run the code in a host its not working.
is this problem for my code or the host?
[image of my problem1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uXVY.png) [image of my problem2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHUAi.png)

```
        // I use this to get folder name:
       // if folder name is "رضا پیشرو" it will display "پیشرو"
            $thistag = basename(getcwd());
      // when I get full url with $_SERVER it shows full folder name but when i want to have just folder name it shows half of it
```

Note that: my folder name is Persian words and it works correct with English words.

Comment: Can you please post the full real path and what you're getting? It's hard to help with an issue if you don't really know what it is.

Comment: Don't post images. We can't copy & paste from them to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It's not a code it's just for know what i mean